# Oracle: cannot start DB becuase DB name in control file came from restored source DB

Tags: oracle, restore, rman

Oracle version 11.2.0.3.

I restored a dev DB from Prod, then i got the following error after partially restored the DB.  I cannot open the DB even in mount.

ORA-01103: database name 'PROD_DB' in control file is not 'DEV_DB'

The restore errors are listed below, I thought I can try to open the DB, but failed from the above error.

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of Duplicate Db command at 09/15/2015 15:43:14
RMAN-05501: aborting duplication of target database
RMAN-03015: error occurred in stored script Memory Script
RMAN-06053: unable to perform media recovery because of missing log
RMAN-06025: no backup of archived log for thread 1 with sequence 171836 and starting SCN of 6104951872 found to restore
RMAN-06025: no backup of archived log for thread 1 with sequence 171835 and starting SCN of 6104939057 found to restore

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After reading some online posts from this website regarding the same error, but the answers were all wrong.  Here is how it worked.

1. I cannot save the control file to trace becuase i cannot open the DB in mount.
2. I cannot change the DB name with the same reason:  cannot mount the DB

So i focused on the RMAN error and went to the Prod db and added a few more archive log backuks to ensure that all logs are saved on the backup device, NetBackup

I then changed the restore time about 20 minutes earlier to ensure i have archive logs there.

It worked like a charm.

Thanks